# Show that there are 64 consecutive integers each of which is divisible by at least one square greater than one ?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

What is "one square greater than 1"? is it just for some x, x^2+1?

Also, I am not really sure how to start this problem.

Help needed.

Comment: x^2 for some value x such that (x^2)>1 .

Comment: Hint: use the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: For example $98,99,100$ are three consecutive integers each of which are divisible by at least one square greater than one.  By this we mean that $98=2\cdot \color{red}{7^2},~99=11\cdot \color{red}{3^2},~100=1\cdot\color{red}{10^2}$.  For a number $n$ to be divisible by at least one square greater than one, this means that we could write $n$ as $n=p\cdot q^2$ with $q$ an integer greater than $1$ and $p$ any integer.

Comment: 1)  All numbers are divisible by $1$ so $1^2$ does not count.  "a square greater than 1" means "a perfect square other than one".  2) Some numbers might be divisible by more than one square.  Ex: if a number is divisible by 16 then it is divisible by 4 as well.  So .... find 64 consecutive integers where each is divisible by a perfect square other than 1.  That's all it's asking.

Answer (score 5):

Hint (over kill):

Let $k_0, ..... , k_{63}$ be $64$ numbers.

Let $a \equiv 0 \mod k_0^2$.

Suppose $a + i \equiv 0 \mod k_i^2$ or to put it another way $a \equiv -i \mod k_i^2$.

Then $a, a+1, a+2....,a+63$ are $64$ consecutive numbers and each one is divisible by a square.

Is there any way we can find such an $a$ and such $k_i$.

Is there any theorem that will let us say that that can be done?
(and under what conditions?)

Something about leftovers and a country.....

Comment: "Something about leftovers and a country....."

I am laughing so hard right now

Comment: 64 co-prime numbers, that should be

Comment: @Cataline fleablood intentionally left that out for the OP to remember the correct statements and hypotheses of the alluded to theorem.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to get how to think about it.  You need to do this and you can do it any way.  The CRT shows you one way but you need to make conditions (which can) be done.

Comment: BTW it's severe overkill.  16 will be divisible by 4 no matter what.  So you don't need 64, and 8 different ones can be dive by 9 so you only need 40 more, not the full 64.

Answer (score 3):

The [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) guarantees that for $\{m_1,m_2,m_3,\ldots,m_n\}$ that are all pairwise coprime then given some $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ there will be a solution to the set of congruences $x\equiv a_i\bmod m_i$.

Taking $m_i= p_i^2$ where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number and $a_i=-i$ with $n=64$ we will have a solution $x$ where the following $64$ numbers $x{+}1, x{+}2, x{+}3, \ldots$ are divisible in turn by the successive prime squares.

Clearly $64$ is not an upper limit; we can find a continuous stretch of any desired length of successive integers that are divisible by square numbers.